# Loading from Redux storage does not overwrite initial state completely

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-storage

it seems that loading from the [Redux storage](https://github.com/react-stack/redux-storage) does not overwrite the initial state completely, and that looks like a bug for me. ( If it's not, please tell me how I can work with it productively. :) )

An example: Let's say, this is my initial state:

```
state = {
  ...
  test: {
    foo: 1,
  }
  ...
}
```

Then, in some dispatch, I change the value of test:

```
nextState.test = { bar: 2 };
```

With redux-storage set up, this is saved (I guess).

When I now close/reopen or reload the whole app, I have this state:

```
state = {
  ...
  test: {
    bar: 2,
    foo: 1,
  }
  ...
}
```

I think, there should be no `foo: 1` at this point, should it?

At least it's bugging me in my app, so what's the correct way of getting rid of it? Is there a config option for `redux-storage` that I can set?

(See the whole code [here](https://github.com/georgjaehnig/qr-show/blob/master/js/codes.js).)